# Plone unit tests do not load dependency package profile

Tags: plone

I've developed an add-on for Plone 4.2 and I'm writing the tests. When I execute

```
# bin/test -s my.stream
```

I got the following error: KeyError: u'profile-my.common:default'
**Why I'm getting that error?**

Here's some information that may be helpfull.

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/blah/user/blah/00-buildout/eggs/zope.testing-3.9.7-py2.6.egg/zope/testing    /testrunner/runner.py", line 366, in run_layer
setup_layer(options, layer, setup_layers)
  File "/blah/user/blah/00-buildout/eggs/zope.testing-3.9.7-py2.6.egg/zope/testing/testrunner/runner.py", line 628, in setup_layer
setup_layer(options, base, setup_layers)
  File "/blah/user/blah/00-buildout/eggs/zope.testing-3.9.7-py2.6.egg/zope/testing/testrunner/runner.py", line 633, in setup_layer
layer.setUp()
  File "/blah/user/blah/00-buildout/eggs/plone.app.testing-4.2-py2.6.egg/plone/app/testing/helpers.py", line 343, in setUp
self.setUpPloneSite(portal)
  File "/blah/user/blah/venv26/buildout/src/my.stream/my/stream/testing.py", line 20,   in setUpPloneSite
applyProfile(portal, 'my.stream:default')
  File "/blah/user/blah/00-buildout/eggs/plone.app.testing-4.2-py2.6.egg/plone/app/testing/helpers.py", line 113, in applyProfile
setupTool.runAllImportStepsFromProfile(profileId)
  File "/blah/user/blah/00-buildout/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.7.1-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/tool.py", line 353, in runAllImportStepsFromProfile
ignore_dependencies=ignore_dependencies)
   - __traceback_info__: profile-my.stream:default
  File "/blah/user/blah/00-buildout/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.7.1-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/tool.py", line 1095, in _runImportStepsFromContext
chain = self.getProfileDependencyChain( profile_id )
  File "/blah/user/blah/00-buildout/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.7.1-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/tool.py", line 1078, in getProfileDependencyChain
chain.extend(self.getProfileDependencyChain( dependency, seen ))
  File "/blah/user/blah/00-buildout/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.7.1-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/tool.py", line 1078, in getProfileDependencyChain
chain.extend(self.getProfileDependencyChain( dependency, seen ))
  File "/blah/user/blah/00-buildout/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.7.1-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/tool.py", line 1076, in getProfileDependencyChain
dependencies = self.getDependenciesForProfile( profile_id )
  File "/blah/user/blah/00-buildout/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.7.1-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/tool.py", line 858, in getDependenciesForProfile
    raise KeyError, profile_id
KeyError: u'profile-my.common:default'
```

**my.stream** depends on **my.common**. Both are add-ons in /blah/user/blah/buildout/src. They are managed by mr.developer.

My buildout includes all development eggs:

```
[buildout]
...
eggs =
  my.common
  my.stream
...

[test]
recipe = zc.recipe.testrunner
defaults = ['--auto-color', '--auto-progress']
eggs =
  ${instance:eggs}
```

My testing.py:

```
from plone.app.testing import PloneSandboxLayer
from plone.app.testing import applyProfile
from plone.app.testing import PLONE_FIXTURE
from plone.app.testing import IntegrationTesting

from zope.configuration import xmlconfig

class MyStreamContent(PloneSandboxLayer):

    defaultBases = (PLONE_FIXTURE,)

    def setUpZope(self, app, configurationContext):
        # Load ZCML
        import my.stream
        xmlconfig.file('configure.zcml',
                       my.stream,
                       context=configurationContext)

    def setUpPloneSite(self, portal):
        applyProfile(portal, 'my.stream:default')

MY__FIXTURE = MyStreamContent()
MY__INTEGRATION_TESTING = IntegrationTesting(
        bases=(MY__FIXTURE,),
        name='MyStreamContent:Integration')
```

What I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make your unit tests to load dependency package ZCMLs. They are not loaded automatically (unlike on Plone startup), as loading all unwanted packages would slow down running tests considerably.

There are several approaches for this, but this could most likely work:

```
def setUpZope(self, app, configurationContext):
    # Load ZCML
    import my.common
    self.loadZCML(package=my.common)

    # my.setup goes here
```

Also, packages should be layered so that if `my.common` provides tests then your `my.stream` test layers would depend on `my.common` layers and remember to call their `super()` methods, so that class hierarchy would take care of initializing dependency packages.

Comment: If you have dependencies' ZCML included in your package's configure.zcml, you can just include your package's ZCML. This works even when using <includeDependencies package="." /> to include ZCML for all dependencies from install_requires in setup.py. But packages that are only configured via z3c.autoinclude will not be configured automatically in tests.

Comment: Thank very much, Mikko and David!